# How to achieve this design in html

Tags: html

I'm going nuts over trying to achieve this simple design with divs and spans instead of tables, tds and trs (I got it working with tables so far)

[image]

Simple design:

- 2 Objects on the left: floating to the left, vertically centered.
- 1 on the right: floating to the right, vertically sent to the bottom.
- All components are on the same line.

I was kinda of hoping this would be easy to write but I found it excruciatingly difficult.
The `float` tag cancels the `vertical-align` tag and I can't get it to work for no combination of styles/divs/spans.

TnX For The Help...

Comment: Share your html/css. And what do you mean by object are those Flash objects or images or text?

Comment: Those are just images and text. I'm just trying to get the design of these 3 elements. I don't have html/css since everything I tried didn't work. I would settle for any text with any image, the reason i need the image in the help is to have a height that is not equal on all three elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/6k8uZ/

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div id="zero">
    <img id="one" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"/>
    <span id="two">General Configuration</span>
    <span id="three">TEST2</span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#zero {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#one, #two {
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#three {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your image is of fixed height, you can float all 3 elements and use `margin-top` to push the text elements down.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear but you can be assured that `vertical-align` only works as expected on table cells and elements that have their `display` property set to `table-cell`.

EDIT: The above is **not correct.** As per duri's link in the comments below, it also applies to **inline** elements. Link: [vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

There are various other "hackish" ways of achieving vertical centering using CSS like negative margins and so on.

Hope this helps.

[Vertical centering using CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Comment: @duri - Not in my experience at all. I'd be happy to remove or change my answer if you could provide an example?

Comment: Very useful article about `vertical-align` can be found at http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Designs like this can only be achieve in CSS if you assign sizes to most elements and then use margins to center them.

You can also try `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` which makes an element behave like a table element.

Or you can save you many days of frustrating work and simply stick with a table. The general consensus[*] is that tables should be used *sparingly* since they were used for everything when there were no `div` tags.

[*] Except for the CSS fanatics, of course.

Comment: No need for margins here. For vertical centering, it's all about the `line-height`.

Comment: @Matt: I suppose that's because `img` and `span` are inline elements? For block elements, I think you need margins.